# ggsave with arrangeGrob fails for large plots (+1 million observations)

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am trying to plot four correlation plots in a 2x2 grid using `ggplot2` and `gridExtra`.

I have four more or less identical plots like this:

```
p1 <- ggplot(d,aes(x,y)) + theme_bw() +
    scale_y_continuous(name="X") +
    scale_x_continuous(name="Y") +
    geom_point()
```

The axes of each plot differ quite a bit, or I would have used `facet_wrap` to plot the four correlations. Instead, I use `arrangeGrob`, like this:

```
g <- arrangeGrob(p1,p2,p3,p4,ncol=2,nrow=2)
ggsave("correlations.pdf",g,dpi=300)
ggsave("c1.pdf",p1,dpi=300)
```

I have included both the saving of the grid as well as one of the plots. The grid results in a blank PDF file (with filesize ~3MB), while the individual plot works.

**My suspicion/additional info:** each of the plots has 270,000 observations, plotted as individual points, for a total >1,000,000. I can imagine how this might give the PDF-rendering trouble.
Can anyone confirm this, and perhaps provide a workaround? Is there a command to let `geom_point` show fewer points/omit overlapping points?

Comment: With that many points you might be better off using hexagonal binning (`geom_hex`).

Comment: Thank you, that was a great suggestion - it works perfectly.